# Are there text processing function that operate on word level in R?

Tags: r, string, nlp, text-processing

I am trying to find a group of functions in R that would operate on word level. e.g. a function that could return the position of the word. For example given the following `sentence` and `query`

```
sentence <- "A sample sentence for demo"
query <- "for"
```

1. the function would return 4. `for` is 4th word.
2. It would be great if I could get a utility function that would allow me to extend `query` both in left and right direction.
   e.g. `extend(query, 'right')` would return `for demo` and `extend(query, 'left')` would return `sentence for`

I have already gone through functions like grep, gregexp, word from stringr package and others. All seem to operate on character level.

Comment: Check out `stringr::word`. As in: `word(string, start = 1L, end = start, sep = fixed(" "))`. You can also use `end = -2L` to get the final two words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written my own functions, the `indexOf` method returns the index of the `word` if it is found in the `sentence` otherwise returns `-1`, very much like [java indexOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String))

```
indexOf <- function(sentence, word){
  listOfWords <- strsplit(sentence, split = " ")
  sentenceAsVector <- unlist(listOfWords)

  if(word %in% sentenceAsVector == FALSE){
    result=-1
  }
  else{
  result = which(sentenceAsVector==word)
  }
  return(result)
}
```

The `extend` method is working properly but is quite lengthy doesn't look like R code at all. If `query` is a word on the boundary of the sentence, i.e. the first word or the last word, first two words or last two words are returned

```
extend <- function(sentence, query, direction){
  listOfWords = strsplit(sentence, split = " ")
  sentenceAsVector = unlist(listOfWords)
  lengthOfSentence = length(sentenceAsVector)
  location = indexOf(sentence, query)
  boundary = FALSE
  if(location == 1 | location == lengthOfSentence){
    boundary = TRUE
  }
  else{
    boundary = FALSE
  } 
  if(!boundary){ 
    if(location> 1 & direction == "right"){  
      return(paste(sentenceAsVector[location], 
                   sentenceAsVector[location + 1],
                   sep=" ")
      )
    }
    else if(location < lengthOfSentence & direction == "left"){
      return(paste(sentenceAsVector[location - 1], 
                   sentenceAsVector[location],
                   sep=" ")
      )

    }
  }
  else{
    if(location == 1 ){
      return(paste(sentenceAsVector[1], sentenceAsVector[2], sep = " "))
    }
    if(location == lengthOfSentence){
      return(paste(sentenceAsVector[lengthOfSentence - 1],
                   sentenceAsVector[lengthOfSentence], sep = " "))
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `scan`, it will split input at whitespace:

```
> s.scan <- scan(text=sentence, what="")
Read 5 items
> which(s.scan == query)
[1] 4
```

Need the `what=""` to tell scan to expect character rather than numeric input. Might need to replace punctuation using `gsub` with `patt="[[:punct:]]"` if your input is ever full English sentences. May also need to look at the `tm` (text mining) package if you are trying to classify parts of speech or handle large documents.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, `stringr` is useful in these instances.

```
library(stringr)

sentence <- "A sample sentence for demo"
wordNumber <- 4L

fourthWord <- word(string = sentence,
                   start = wordNumber)

previousWords <- word(string = sentence,
                       start = wordNumber - 1L,
                       end = wordNumber)

laterWords <- word(string = sentence,
                   start = wordNumber,
                   end = wordNumber + 1L)
```

And this yields:

```
> fourthWord
[1] "for"
> previousWords
[1] "sentence for"
> laterWords
[1] "for demo"
```

I hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what you mean by a "word". If you mean whitespace-separated token, then @imran-ali's answer works fine. If you mean word as defined by Unicode, with special attention to punctuation, then you need something more sophisticated.

The following handles punctuation correctly:

```
library(corpus)
sentence <- "A sample sentence for demo"
query <- "for"

# use text_locate to find all instances of the query, with context
text_locate(sentence, query)
##   text             before              instance              after              
## 1 1                 A sample sentence    for     demo             

# find the number of tokens before, then add 1 to get the position
text_ntoken(text_locate(sentence, query)$before) + 1
## 4
```

This also works if there are multiple matches:

```
sentence2 <- "for one, for two! for three? for four"
text_ntoken(text_locate(sentence2, query)$before) + 1
## [1]  1  4  7 10
```

We can verify that this is correct:

```
text_tokens(sentence2)[[1]][c(1, 4, 7, 10)]
## [1] "for" "for" "for" "for"
```